# download tweet from specific tweet id

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

```
from TweetStore import TweetStore
from TwitterAPI.TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI


COUCH_DATABASE = 'test_db1'
TWITTER_ENDPOINT = 'statuses/filter'
TWITTER_PARAMS = {'track':'football','language':'en',}

API_KEY ="aaa"
API_SECRET = "bbb"
ACCESS_TOKEN ="ccc"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "ddd"


storage = TweetStore(COUCH_DATABASE)

api = TwitterAPI(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)


for item in api.request(TWITTER_ENDPOINT, TWITTER_PARAMS):
    if 'text' in item:
    print('%s -- %s\n' % (item['user']['screen_name'], item['text']))
    storage.save_tweet(item)
    elif 'message' in item:
    print('ERROR %s: %s\n' % (item['code'], item['message']))
```

Using these code we can download tweets but i want to download tweet from specific tweet id. i have been given some tweet id and want to download tweet text and other attrib of those tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [read the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid)?

You need to hit the end point `statuses/show` and the parameter of `'id':'1234'`